# AppleScript: How to get URL of Safari tab which failed to load?

Tags: safari, applescript

Here's how I get the URL：

```
tell application "Safari"    
set _URL to URL of current tab of front window    
end tell
```

For the page who successfully opened, I got the right URL. But for those who failed to open, which state "Failed to open page" as the tab name and "Safari Can't Find the Server" as the page content, the URL is not the real website address.

What I got is:

> file:///Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Resources/

So how can I get what is really in the Safari address bar when the page failed to open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably still physically grab the text in the address field using UI scripting.

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        key code 37 using {command down}
        key code 8 using {command down}
        delay 0.1
        key code 53
    end tell
end tell
set _URL to the clipboard
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you soooo much. There's still so much to learn.

Comment: Hi can I ask about how do you know

Comment: How do I know the key codes? You can find a full list here:  http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.com/2014/12/key-codes-for-function-and-special-keys.html